# Trying to install an R package from github but get this error message (on two different computers)

Tags: r, github

I get the following error message

```
Warning: S3 method 'ggplot.egp3RangeFit' was declared in NAMESPACE 
but not found
Error in namespaceExport(ns, exports) : 
undefined exports: addVariables, getAggregateData, getBaselines, 
getStudyDay
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed for 'i386', 'x64'
```

I've also tried manually downloading the zip file and putting it in my library and that hasn't worked either. I'm not sure what else to try

Comment: are you on a 64 bit machine and R installation?

Comment: I'm not sure its says Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit) on my R console when I load it

Comment: post the name of the package here

Comment: library(devtools)
install_github("harrysouthworth/margarita")

Comment: I just tried to download and got the same error. I used another Github installer and it failed as well. there is likely an issue with the package. I would open a ticket with the developer on Github

Comment: Tried and also failed. I've opened an issue on Github: https://github.com/harrysouthworth/margarita/issues/9

Comment: Thank you the installer has now resolved it :)